# Count freq values and keep all rows - multiple conditions

Tags: r, count, frequency

I need to create a new column with the frequency of two conditions (defined in each row) considering the whole dataset.

Please note that I need to add this information and keep all rows in the previous dataset.

Example:

```
library(datasets)
mydata<-CO2
names(mydata)
[1] "Plant"     "Type"      "Treatment" "conc"      "uptake"
```

Suppose I want to use the variables 'Type' and 'Treatment' as my conditions.
So, I would need to count for each row how many times the respective 'Type' and 'Treatment' appears in the whole dataset.

Comment: You need to count for each row how many times the respective *combination* of 'Type' and 'Treatment' appears?

Comment: exactly this! thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ave` to calculate the length of each of the grouping pairs:

```
mydata$freq <- ave(rep(1, nrow(mydata)), mydata$Type, mydata$Treatment, FUN = length)

head(mydata)
#  Plant   Type  Treatment conc uptake freq
#1   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled   95   16.0   21
#2   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  175   30.4   21
#3   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  250   34.8   21
#4   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  350   37.2   21
#5   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  500   35.3   21
#6   Qn1 Quebec nonchilled  675   39.2   21
```

Comment: Exactly what I was doing, you beat me by some tens of seconds.

Comment: Ah, I only had it on my mind since I just answered another question with a very similar solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do this with `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
mydata %>% group_by(Type,Treatment) %>% summarize(count = n())
```

will result in

```
# A tibble: 4 x 3
# Groups:   Type [?]
         Type  Treatment count
       <fctr>     <fctr> <int>
1      Quebec nonchilled    21
2      Quebec    chilled    21
3 Mississippi nonchilled    21
4 Mississippi    chilled    21
```